# Redis cloud connection refused on production laravel application

Tags: laravel, redis, connection

My publicly hosted laravel application refuse to connect to Redis Cloud database, however it works when i try it on 127.0.0.1:8000.

This is my .env redis configuration:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis-13652.c304.europe-west1-2.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:13652
REDIS_PASSWORD=********* #this is not my real password
REDIS_PORT=13652
```

Here is my redis configuration in database.php:

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: You should try to connect using redis-cli first to see if it's an issue on the host side or client side. Get redis-cli and run `redis-cli -h redis-13652.c304.europe-west1-2.gce.cloud.redislabs.com -p 13652`.